# GitLab CI/CD shell executor: npm command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

On my server, I have configured the gitlab runner to use the `shell` executor. And `which node` command gives: `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.11.0/bin/node`.

So, my gitlab-ci.yml file has the following:

```yaml
stages:
  - prepare
  - check
  - deploy

default:
  before_script:
    - export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.11.0/bin

prepare:
  stage: prepare
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
  before_script:
    - export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.11.0/bin
  script:
    - npm i --ignore-scripts --include=dev
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

The `prepare` job, throws `npm: command not found` error, and the pipeline fails.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to your `script:` step, *before* the `npm` command line:

```
- echo "PATH='${PATH}'"
```

That way, you can check if the path is actually modified.

Try adding quotes:

```
- export PATH="$PATH:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.11.0/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Shell executor uses `.profile` to load env. You can make gitlab-runner use nvm by adding this to gitlab-runners `$HOME/.profile`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding in `.profile` of `gitlab-runner user`. It works for me on ubuntu 20.04

Shell executor uses `.profile` to load `env`. You can make `gitlab-runner` use `nvm` by adding this to `gitlab-runners $HOME/.profile`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install nvm in the correct user in this case gitlab-runner

```
sudo -iu gitlab-runner   #change user to gitlab-runner
touch ~/.profile #create profile file
```

Install nvm